# Server Features to MVC application

Tags: wcf, asp.net-mvc-4, iis, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2012

Hi I'm developing an aplication on Framework 4.5 and MVC 4 using Windows Comunication Foundation, I have a DB on Sql Server 2008, I want to ask about the server features do you recommend, I have to change Sql Server 2008 database to 2012?

Windows server 2012?? How they work together?
IIS 8?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you asking if you need to use Sql server 2012?  No, you don't.  No, you don't need to use Windows server 2012.  No, you don't need to use IIS 8.  You *CAN* use any of them, but you don't have to.

I really don't understand your question.  It's very vague.  The best I can say is, there is no problem using MVC with any version of Windows, Sql Server, or IIS that is currently supported by Microsoft.

FYI, MVC is database agnostic.  It doesn't do any database access.  You are probably going to use a framework like Entity Framework with MVC, which doesn't change this answer at all.

As for a recommendation of server features, there is nothing that affects MVC or Entity Framework.  If you want a feature, then you need to use a server that supports that feature.  That's all there is to it.

Comment: Thanks I heard about troubles of IIS 8 on Windows Sever 2012, thank you for your comments

Comment: @JVazquez - What you have probably heard is that people are unfamiliar with it, and don't know how to configure it correctly.